# how to Invoke process action aftter creating it?

Tags: java

i am writing simple class which create a process and i wish to use the actions(methods) this process can do and i dont know how..

my simple method is :

```
 public void initProcesses()
    {
        Process pA;
        Process pB;
        Process pC;

        try 
        {
            pA = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -cp ProccesA.java ");
                    Class<ProccesA> a = pA.getClass<ProccesA>();
        } 
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

now, i am not really sure i know if getclass will help (and i know i can use reflation instead) but i need to do this with process so this is my problem,

any suggestion someone on how i can use my proccess ProccessA.Java and use hie methods ?

thanks

Comment: So, you want to compile a java file, then run some methods from it? Did I understand you right?

Comment: Why do you want to start your Java class in another process?

Comment: i am writing a server which build from couple of process and each one of the process can do one thing, when client sent request the server should be looking for the write process which can do the job.

Answer (score 0):

`Runtime.exec()` is usually meant to start non-Java processes from within Java. It is not possible to access anything *within* that process (except things like stdout and stderr).

Probably you might want to do something like this:

```
ProcessA instance = new ProcessA();
instance.someMethod();
```

Comment: i see but i am writing a server which build from couple of process and each one of the process can do one thing, when client sent request the server should be looking for the write process which can do the job

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you can't directly call methods on a Java object in another process.

However, you could use [Java RMI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/index.html), or build your own similar sort of interface using [sockets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/).

Do consider carefully whether or not you really need a separate process, however, as inter-process communication complicates the code and has a lot of performance overhead.